# Diawi shows wrong identifer of the app

Tags: ios, iphone, installation, ios9, diawi

I have created app with today and watch kit extension. App build successfully and created IPA. This IPA is also install in device using iTune sync. but when I upload this IPA to diawi and download in device it did not download. Also I have notice that diawi show wrong bundle identifer. I have used Identifer as below

- For iOS app **com.appname.ios**
- For Widget extension **com.appname.widget**
- For Watchkit extension **com.appname.watchkit**

As my app is using **com.appname.ios** identifier but diawi is showing **com.appname.watchkit**. I don't know why this happen. but because of this issue I am not able to install app in device from Diawi